# hide a field of virtual population mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

i have a comment collection and a post collection, and post schema are like this:

```
postSchema.virtual("comments", {
  ref: "Comment",
  localField: "_id",
  foreignField: "post",
})
```

and when i want to see comments of a post i use this:

```
   const post = await Post.findById(req.params.id);
    await post.populate("comments");
    res.send(post.comments);
```

i dont want to get email field of post.comments. i tried foreach delete key and it didnt work
tnx for helping me

Comment: Does this work? `.populate({ path: 'comments', select: '-email' })`

Comment: how can i hide multiple field? like 3 field of it

Comment: Add more exclusions: `select: '-email -field2 -field3'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the regular [field selection method](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#field-selection) for `.populate` with virtuals too:

```
await post.populate("comments", "-email");
// or if you want to exclude more than one field:
// await post.populate("comments", "-email -field2 -field3");
```

If you want to use *positive* selection (which fields *should* be included in the result), make sure that you always include the `foreignField` of the virtual (in this case `post`):

```
await post.populate("comments", "post field2 field3");
```